# show pdf in android application

Tags: android, pdf

I have a PDF file in `resource/raw/color_chart_ciao.pdf` in my application.I want to show that file in my application. I have written code for that:

```
File file = new File("http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf");
        System.out.println("FIle Path is" + file);
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("FIle Path is" + file);
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
                System.out.println("pdf show");
            } 
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(CiaoView.this, 
                    "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

but I can't see the PDF on my application when i run my application.
I am fresher in application development. So please help with this question.

Answer (score 0):

if you have any default PDF reader installed in the device/emulator then only you can open the **PDF** through intent but your application will not be a **stand alone** application. If you want to make your application stand alone  then you have to implement **PDF** reader in your application . There are **open source project** on **PDF** read your that can follow.

Here are few links for **PDF**:

1. [apdf](http://code.google.com/p/apdf/)
2. [mupdf](http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/)

Answer (score 0):

-Copy the following code in your activity. Call the function CopyReadAssets("File_name.pdf") from where ever you want. Place the File_name.pdf file in assets folder. It'll work! Happy Coding! :)

```
private void CopyReadAssets(String pdfname)
{
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), pdfname);
try
{
    in = assetManager.open(pdfname);
    out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    copyFile(in, out);
    in.close();
    in = null;
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    out = null;
} catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pdf Viewer not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
try
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(
        Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/"+pdfname),
        "application/pdf");

startActivity(intent);
}catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pdf Viewer not installed" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}