# android: download a pdf file and open after

Tags: android, pdf, android-download-manager

I'm trying to download a pdf doc from internet and after that, when download ends, open it automatically throught a package.

I found some solutions for downloading by DownloadManager but no answer to open it after. One of the codes I've tested is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                        DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                Query query = new Query();
                query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = c
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                            .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                        String uriString = c
                                .getString(c
                                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);

                        intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                        startActivity(intent);



                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Request request = new Request(
            Uri.parse("http://www.xxxxxxx.org/directory/abc.pdf"));
    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);

}
```

but when the download ends successfully, the package don't find the file.

I need your help. I have spent two weeks looking for a solutions via google and android books with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: For the temporary  solution , Install the adode reader in the phone and REad it :    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488265/show-pdf-in-android-application

Answer (score 0):

Create  this method and call it in your code

```
public void showPdf() {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Download/" + name + "CV.pdf");//name here is the name of any string you want to pass to the method
        if (!file.isDirectory())
            file.mkdir();
        Intent testIntent = new Intent("com.adobe.reader");
        testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        testIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        testIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        startActivity(testIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or else you can refer my answer here.

[How to use Asynchronous task for download progress dialog in fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260810/how-to-use-asynchronous-task-for-download-progress-dialog-in-fragment/40394318#40394318)

Its for downloading file and displaying progress diolog.Here i used asynch task.Call above method in onpost() method of asynch task.
Hope it helps you too